# Push Notifications for Mac OS

Tags: swift, macos, push-notification

Its possible to receive Push Notifications in Mac OS, while the application is closed?

In iOS, you dont need to have the app in background/foreground/open to receive a Push notification, its the same behavior to Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's documentation ([APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1)):

> Apple Push Notification service (APNs) is the centerpiece of the remote notifications feature. It is a robust, secure, and highly efficient service for app developers to propagate information to iOS (and, indirectly, watchOS), tvOS, and macOS devices.

Yes, it is the same for macOS.